# How to change HighChart xAxis timeline to match local time and not UTC?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, utc, timeline

[image]

Note above in my screenshot, the tooltip is displaying the correct local time. However the xAxis timeline is showing 12:00pm UTC time.

I have `global:useUTC` set false in 2 places:

In my chartConfig:

```
 vm.config = {
    global: { useUTC : false }, // <--
    options: {
    // ....
```

As well as in my setHighCharts function which gets run after the chart is loaded:

```
const setHighChartOptions = (color, background, gridLine) => {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: { useUTC: false }, // <--
        chart: {
            backgroundColor: background
        },
        legend: {
            itemStyle: { color: color }
        },
        loading: {
            labelStyle: { color: color },
            style: { backgroundColor: background }
        },
        xAxis: { labels: {style: { color: color }}}
    });

    chart.get('y-axis-price').update({
        gridLineColor: gridLine,
        gridLineDashStyle: 'longdash'
    }, false);

    chart.get('x-axis-sentiment').update({
        tickColor: background
    }, false);

    chart.get('x-axis-alert').update({
        tickColor: background
    }, false);
};
```

Anything I'm missing? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured this out!

The `global` object in my `chartConfig` was useless.... the key was the setHighChartOptions function. That needed to run in order to set the `useUTC` to false.

Problem was in my app, that function only gets called if you change themes. So now I just call it right away after the chart is loaded and now the `useUTC` gets set to false correctly.

```
const initHighChart = (chart, urlObject) => {
    setHighChartOptions('#fff', '#474747', '#656565');
    let ticker = urlRetrieve.ticker(urlObject);
    let epoch  = urlRetrieve.epochs(urlObject);
    setNewChartTicker(chart, ticker, epoch.start, epoch.end);
};
```

Comment: Nice ! 8 minutes after asking the question ^^ It shows how efficient it is to clearly write down the issue !